# How to make a Foreign Key with unique=true to be "optional" in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-users

I have a User Model (pre-defined by Django) and a UserProfile model connected via a ForeignKey.

I'm creating two separate ModelForms to use in a single template as a registration form of sorts.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name="connector")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

However, when I load the page and fill in the form information, the UserProfileForm requires me to select / fill in the user field in order to validate.

This "user", however, is the one that is being created right now so I can't choose a "user" as it has not been created yet / is still being created.

I know this user is field has the attribute unique=true but there a way to make this field "optional"?

My view (below) should handle it such that once the user object is created, i will set the foreign key of UserProfile to this newly created user object (unless I am doing something wrong my views.py as well).

views.py

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = UserForm(request.POST)
        form2 = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            #create initial entry for user
            username = form1.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form1.cleaned_data["password"]
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
            new_user.save()

            #create entry for UserProfile (extension of new_user object)      
            profile = form2.save(commit = False)
            profile.user = new_user
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/books/")
    else:
        form1 = UserForm()
        form2 = UserProfileForm()
    c = {
        'form1':form1,
        'form2':form2,
    }
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("registration/register.html", c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could set:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, related_name="connector")
```

which would make the user relationship optional, but I don't think this is what you need. Instead, why not just remove the `user` field from the `UserProfile` form and manually assign it, instead of letting the user see the dropdown at all. Then there would be no validation error.

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ("user", )
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply exclude the field from the form.

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    exclude = ('user',)
```